# How to drag and drop from mat-menu to another element on the page (using cdkdrag Angular Material)

Tags: angular, menu, angular-material2, angular-cdk-drag-drop, angular-cdk-overlay

Is there any way to drag from mat-menu and drop to another element on the page (using cdkdrag)?
The approach taken by [greatweatherforducks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2107779/greatweatherforducks) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182418/drag-and-drop-from-mat-menu-to-section) is very interesting, but it doest use cdkdrag, just the DragEvent interface.

I have tried to adapt that solution, but I couldn't find nothing like the dataTransfer property on cdkdrag.